# Pin Binary instrumentation: How to precisely identify a function name.

Tags: c++, c, binary, instrumentation, intel-pin

Anyone who's used PIN? How would you identify a function exactly (in presence of method overloading)? I can see PIN provides RTN_Name() function, which would return the function name, but surely that's no enough… so what else would you use? Would using RTN_Address() in conjunction with RT_Name() suffice?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: ok I just found out about name mangling! It seems even using RTN_Name() should suffice then!

Comment: consider answering your own question for posterity's sake. You might even get upvotes from people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I just found out about name mangling! Apparently C/C++ uses [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), and so it seems that even using `RTN_Name()` should suffice then!